# Excel VBA Copy Paste After Search

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

My macro should simply copy paste a block of data.

My problem is, that it only copies the data into one  column, and I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
Sheets("Auswertung").Select
Daten = Range("L4:R17")
Sheets("Übersicht").Select

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

For S = 2 To Range("nz85").End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Cells(85, S) = Sheets("Auswertung").Range("L3") Then
        Range(Cells(86, S), Cells(98, S)) = Daten
        Exit For
    End If
```

Row 85 contains dates. I want to copy the data in a certain date. `Daten` contains the information of the date if "L3" and the next 6 days. So one week of data. 
I thought I can simply put the data of one week into `Daten` and the paste it on the first day of the week in the hope that it will also paste the next 6 days. The problem is that it only pastes in the date in one column.

How could i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Range(Cells(86, S), Cells(98, S+6)) = Daten
```

Answer (score 0):

**Important Note**: you are trying to Paste to 13 rows `Range(Cells(86, S), Cells(98, S))` is = 98 - 86 + 1 = **13 rows**. While `Daten = Range("L4:R17")` is actually **14 rows**. Therefore, you are getting your error, because the size of the `Range` and your `Daten` array don't match.

The same goes for the size of your `Column`, you can copy 6 columns into 1. (as mentioned also by @h2so4)

So either your `Daten` need to be modified, or maybe it's `Range(Cells(86, S), Cells(99, S))` ?

Also, you can achieve what you are trying to without all the unnecessary `Select` of the different sheets. Just use fully qualified `Range` and `Cells` like the code below:

```
Daten = Sheets("Auswertung").Range("L4:R17").Value

With Worksheets("Übersicht")
    For s = 2 To .Range("NZ85").End(xlToLeft).Column
        If .Cells(85, s) = Sheets("Auswertung").Range("L3").Value Then
            ' ******* MODIFY ONE OF THE PARAMETERS AT THE LINE BELOW *******
            .Range(.Cells(86, s), .Cells(98, s)).Value = Daten
            Exit For
        End If
    Next s
End With
```